# Function app works good in visual studio but after publishing it throws error when i call the function from logic apps

Tags: json, azure-function-app

my Scenario: passing the JSON data to function app to do some business functions like converting the input JSON to the correct format, for this i have used foreach loops and creating a json string.

the abopve scenario worked as expecting in local VS2017, but after publishing and while calling from logic apps it throws error.

to check manually i copied entire code into  function app(Azure portal) and checked there when i called the function app, it shown some errors related to my JSON.

1. Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.at `data[0].columns.Count`

then i have added another foreach on top of the other `foreach` and tried to take count as `totalData["columns"].Count`

2. Cannot access child value on `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty`. (when i place `data[0].columns.Count` to `totalData["columns"].Count`)

can you please help me how can the function app gives output same as VS2017 output. or working with json in function app.

[image]

Comment: Could you update the code not the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Cause you said you get the error in the portal and you post the code you local function. So I write a simple code to read the json data from request. And you don't mention your json schema, so the below is my test json data and the `CSX` code.

```
[
    {"columns":{
    "count":1
},
"rows":[1,2]},
{"columns":{
    "count":2
},
"rows":[3,4]}]
```

**function.csx:**

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // Get request body
        dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    int count = data[1].columns.count;
    int row = data[1].rows[0];

    log.Info("colums: "+count.ToString()+" row:"+row);
}
```

And here is the result pic:

[image]

If this json data is not what you want or you still have other questions, please feel free to let me know or provide more details.

Comment: this was resolved by checking my json object structure which i send from logic apps

Comment: @SAI krishna , so you have solved your problem, you could post your solution and accept it as the answer to help others.